# upload file is not storing the destination folder using multer in nodejs

Tags: node.js

```
router.post('/uploadDocuments', function (req, res) {
  console.log("uploadDocuments");
 console.log(req.files.file);

  var storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, './temp')
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + path.extname(file.originalname))
    }
});

const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

});
```

In console i can see the upload file details

```
{
  name: 'doc-file.jpg',
  data: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 01 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff db 00 84 00 07 07 07 07 07 07 08 08 08 08 0b 0b 0a 0b 0b 10 0e 0d 0d 0e 10 18 11 12 11 ... 93509 more bytes>,
  size: 93559,
  encoding: '7bit',
  tempFilePath: '',
  truncated: false,
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  md5: '19f413e98d9f275691ffd6b53062cf88',
  mv: [Function: mv]
}
```

From postman to upload a file getting issues.I checked the folder permission also
[image]

Comment: Is there any error ?

Comment: it's not showing any error

Comment: I've updated my answer with live demo link. Please check it out.

Comment: i have added const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');so it stops to upload.i removed the line from app.js.Then it's  worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Actually you need to specify the handler like the following.

```
const upload = multer({ storage: storage }).any();
```

[Live Demo](https://repl.it/repls/GuiltyGrandioseParallelcomputing#index.js)

FYI:

multer(options) is an object

multer(options).any() is a function

Other handlers

```
.single(fieldname) -> Accept a single file with the name fieldname
.array(fieldname[, maxCount]) -> Accept an array of files, all with the name fieldname
.fields(fields) -> Accept a mix of files, specified by fields
.none() -> Accept only text fields.
.any() -> Accepts all files that comes over the wire.
```

References

[Mutter - NPM](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer)

Comment: in req.files have the details of the upload file name.How to upload req.files data

Comment: I've added a link for live demo. Please check it out.

Answer (score 0):

Should I recommend using **Formidable**. 
That would be:

```
const formidable = require('formidable');

const form = new formidable.IncomingForm();
form.uploadDir = 'Specify your folder';
```

(by default takes the folder at root directory);

This will automatically upload your image to your desired folder.